# Redirecionar página após login

Tags: angular

Estou tentando fazer um redirecionamento para a página inicial após fazer login, mas o sistema não sai do login

Código de teste que fiz para demonstração é esse:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      login:    new FormControl('', {validators: [Validators.required], 'updateOn': 'blur'}),
      password: new FormControl('', {validators: [Validators.required]})
    }, );
    this.navigateTo = this.activedRoute.snapshot.params['to'] || '/estacao';
  }
  login() {
     this.router.navigate(['/pagina'])
  }
```

Este é o código do botão

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)
```

Segue um exemplo no stackblits: [aqui](https://angularcli-login.stackblitz.io) e [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularcli-login)

Arquivo com as rotas:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: ':to', component: LoginComponent},
  {
    path: 'pagina',
    component: SistemaComponent, // Layout diferente da página de login
    children: [
      {path: '', component: PaginaComponent}
    ]
  }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    path: 'pagina',
    component: SistemaComponent, // Layout diferente da página de login
    children: [
      {path: '', component: PaginaComponent}
    ]
  }, 
{path: '', component: LoginComponent},
{path: ':to', component: LoginComponent}
```

As rotas são escolhidas por ordem, e no seu caso estava sempre redirecionando para a login. A ordem importa muito para as rotas funcionarem corretamente.